# recompiling a huge software stack like mozilla

Tags: configure

A small change in a 1000's of lines of code leads to running the ./configure again on the entire software.

Is there any alternative, where we can compile only the changed file and the files associated with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a sane `Makefile.am` with proper dependencies, running `./configure` and `make` should only recompile files that depend on the touched file. So `make` already does what you are asking for.

If your Makefiles are not sane (e.g. they only work if you run `make clean`) and you are compiling C or C++ sources, using [ccache](http://ccache.samba.org/) might give you a speed gain. With ccache only the preprocessor part is run and its output compared to a cache of compile outputs. If nothing changed in the file or its includes it won't be recompiled. Properly installed it is run in a transparent way.